# How to get the index of an item in a SortedSet

Tags: scala, sortedset

I am implementing some kind of "record matrix" where the axis indices are (unique) keys of some type `K` (eg. String). These keys doesn't need to be sorted but I need an order, so I went for a SortedSet.

The main purpose of the keys (SortedSet) are to find the actual integer index in the underlying 2 dimensional data array (`Seq[Seq[.]]` or what ever).
But I cannot find a ways to get such a `f(key: K): Int` function.

Instead of a `SortedSet[K]`, I could use a `Map[K,Int]` which values are the indices, but I find that overkill (and not well typed).

Any idea?

**Edit**

The Map method is something like, but in 2D:

```
val myKeys = // SortedSet("A", "B", "C")
val data   = // Array(13,42,117)
val keyIndices = myKeys.zipWithIndex.toMap

// get indices of "B", and lookup in data array
data(keyIndices("B"))
```

I wrote "not well typed" for the Map solution because the type does not guaranty the indices are consecutive and starting at 0. While the position in an ordered seq is.

**Selected solution**

I selected [Neumann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35224438/1206998) because it was best for my actual problem. But [Cipcigan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35224103/1206998) and [Verkerk's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35224340/1206998) answers suits more the title.

Comment: Why is Map overkill and not well typed? If I understand your question, it  is the function K => Int that you say you want.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do. Could you provide some code as to how you use this? How would you use the key and how would you use the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

Keeping the`Set` you can not. Having a way to get an element by index is a trait of a `Seq`.

```
scala> val data =scala.collection.SortedSet("a", "l", "m", "o", "n", "d")
data: scala.collection.SortedSet[String] = TreeSet(a, d, l, m, n, o)

scala> data(1)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
found   : Int(1)
required: String
   data(1)
        ^

scala> data("a")
res3: Boolean = true
```

I this example it is shown that the apply method checks if given argument is contained in the set.

I would go with the approach you already suggested by using the `Map`. Or transform the data to a `Seq`

```
scala> val indexedData = data.toVector
indexedData: Vector[String] = Vector(a, d, l, m, n, o)

scala> indexedData(2)
res9: String = l

scala> indexedData.indexOf("l")
res1: Int = 2
```

Comment: Actually, what I need is: `key("l") => 3` so that I can do `value(rowKey("rowName"))(colKey("colName"))` where value is the underlying 2d data array (in short)

Comment: Added an example how to use `indexOf`. This should give you what you want ;)

Comment: indexOf is what I'm looking for. But why is it not defined for sortedSet !! :-( I guess, indexOf is O(n) and the map solution is O(1), but a big, inefficient O(1) and badly typed for my problem.
I guess I'll just try to avoid calling it too much

Comment: "and badly typed " again, what do you  mean here? The types are just fine,as far as I can see. Do you have some other meaning of "badly typed"?

Comment: I edited the question to explain the "badly typed" issue. It's no big deal really because I use those only privately

Answer (score 2):

Using `zipWithIndex` should do it:

```
def getIndex[T](xs: scala.collection.SortedSet[T], x:T): Option[Int] =
   xs.zipWithIndex.find(_._1 == x).map(_._2)

val a = scala.collection.SortedSet("a", "l", "m", "o", "n", "d")

getIndex(a, "a") // => Some(0)
getIndex(a, "m") // => Some(3)
getIndex(a, "x") // => None
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an implicit class to add the functionality to SortedSet

```
implicit class SortedListFunctions[T](val s: SortedSet[T]){
    def getIndex(key: T): Int = {
        val notDropped = s.dropWhile(_ != key).size

        if(notDropped == 0) -1
        else s.size - notDropped
    }
}
```

With the implicit class you can call getIndex(..) a if it existed in the API

```
 set.getIndex(key)
```

Note that this might not be a very efficient way to search something which is sorted.
If your SortedSet is really big you might consider [Binary Searching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) it

Comment: Good solution but (I know I should not say that when in scala context) I don't like implicit :-/

Comment: Yes, maybe it's to much.